# Placing Box In CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 3 boxes on a page, and I want to place them next to each other. which code should I use?
Margin?
Padding?
Which display? Inline or Block?

```css
.box{
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(158, 235, 158, 0.151);
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-color: rgb(13, 54, 31);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1"/>
<div class="box-2"/>
<div class="box-3"/>
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your snippet which you may like to correct - depending on what you want the effect to be. Your divs appear on top of one another as they are not terminated explicitly. They are interpreted as nested. The .box setting does not get applied as you have no class="box" set. Depending on what you want eventually you might investigate display inline-block or display flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use `display: flex` which has `flex-direction: row` by default. In addition, it is possible to set width in percents:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
    width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using flexbox its quite easy. just set the parent element flex direction to row.

```
<div id="row">
  <div id="box-1" />
  <div id="box-2" />
  <div id="box-3" />
</div>

#row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS that you have written there is a selector named `box` while no class `box` you have used in the HTML divs.

Also starting curly bracket is missing while writing your CSS for selector `box`.

First correct this syntax and then you can use `display:flex;` on the parent container of the 3 divs.

Also divs are paired tags, so you must use the closing div also.

```css
.container{
 display:flex;
}
.box{
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  width: 350px;height: 200px;
  background-color:rgba(158, 235, 158, 0.151);
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dashed; 
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-color: rgb(13, 54, 31);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1 box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box-2 box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box-3 box">Box 3</div>
</div>
```